# Is it possible to directly reference doxygen built-in modules in the layout file?

Tags: doxygen

I am trying to customize doxygen output using the layout file.

```
<tab type="modules" visible="yes" title="" intro="">
    <tab type="user" visible="yes" title="High-level document interface" url="@ref Documents"/>
    <tab type="user" visible="yes" title="Low-level file interface" url="@ref Files"/>
    <tab type="user" visible="yes" title="Utilities" url="@ref Utils"/>
    <tab type="user" visible="yes" title="Types" url="@ref Types"/>
</tab>
```

The output has one minor problem, that the user defined pages are duplicated in the tree view.

[image]

I have tried using custom user group and referencing the modules from the layout file as following:

```
<tab type="usergroup" visible="yes" url="@ref modules" title="Modules">
```

However I end up with error: "**explicit link request to 'modules' in layout file 'doxygen_layout.xml' could not be resolved**"

This can be solved referencing the modules.html file.

```
<tab type="usergroup" visible="yes" url="modules.html" title="Modules">
```

I was really surprised this works, but I am not sure if it is the most bullet-proof solution.

**Can I create drop-down modules menu?**

**Can I directly reference to modules page?**

Note:
Referencing non-existing html file does not produce any warning nor error in the output.

```
<tab type="usergroup" visible="yes" url="asdf.html" title="Modules">
```